# Professional relationship and friendship with the same person

Tags: professionalism, relationships, business

I live in a city with very difficult (and expensive) rent situation. I rent an apartment and I have some loans to pay off. To share the costs (and to make some profit), I decided to look for a roommate. I decided to maintain a professional relationship as I don't wanted to concede upon the terms of living together that we had agreed upon.

The person was very friendly, I responded in a friendly way. And I thought that we could be friends. But, being a landlord, I have to enforce certain rules and I don't want to be at a losing on the terms that I had agreed with him before.

I am finding hard to straddle between professional relationships and friendships. Is it a good idea to mix professional relationship with other kinds of relationships? Is it ever possible to have more than professional relationship? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Basically, I am doing business with someone and making a profit, can I still be friends with them?

---

Adding more context:

In the beginning, the person did many friendly gesture, like offered some nice food that he had cooked, took initiatives to clean the bathroom (better than I had expected), offered to watch movies together. So, several instances of activities that people would do together as friends.

At the beginning, we had agreed upon certain rules of living together. He followed them all, but eventually I observed that he started flouting those rules a bit, after I had reciprocated his friendly behavior.

He asked for lesser rent and more favorable terms for him (than what was negotiated before). I am feeling that I am having difficulty denying him those favors, even though it is diverging from what we had negotiated.

Overall I think he is a good person, and I might not find another person (as a roommate) who is as good as him. So, I could not deny him lesser rent (it's still more than 50% of the actual rent that I pay) even though, I feel the original terms were better for me.

So, now I am regretting that I should have maintained strictly professional relationship with my roommate. But, I am not sure, if it's the right thing to do.

Comment: "*can I still be friends with them?*": it's up to you, *you* have to decide what kind of relationship you want to maintain...

Comment: Sure. If they run into a problem paying the rent the friendship may make it more difficult to maintain, especially if you assert that they must pay and do not given them a break as a friend would. Basically if things all go well, it would be fine. It is if things go wrong it may get difficult.

Comment: Is this person lagging on their rent payments or something? And thus why you ask about the balance of being friends and telling someone "rent is due, pay by tomorrow"

Comment: @DarkCygnus I edited with more context

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make some profit", but that already sounds like this is not a friendship

Comment: @cdkMoose It began as a professional relationship. I was making some profit as the rent that I charged was more than 50%. I had made a competitive offer, and during our negotiation he had accepted that offer. But later he started showing some friendly behavior. To which I responded in a friendly way. Now, he is flouting the agreement a bit, and I am finding it difficult to mention it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere When we do business with friends, do we have to give them more discount than usual? If we don't give more discount than usual they might think that we are selfish. But professionally, I would not want to give more discount than usual. So, in this case do you think its possible to have a friendly relationship and to be professional?

Comment: *"So, I could not deny him lesser rent (it's still more than 50% of the actual rent that I pay) even though"* - this reads unfair. You are 2 living there. Costs "should" be 50/50

Comment: @DarkCygnus Its not because my rental agreement is old. And the current price that we had negotiated is based on the current market situation. He had asked me how much I pay, later when there was some friendly interactions. The time at which we had negotiated the terms, he was stranger to me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere But isn't doing favors, a part of friendship?

Comment: When you say professional relationship, do you work together or are you referring to the lessor/lessee relationship?

Comment: @cdkMoose lessor/lessee relationship

Comment: For me it would be hard to define professional vs friend when the whole relationship is defined by living in the same space.  I don't believe you actually have the role of landlord here(since I don't think you own/control the property), it's more of renting out a room which makes it hard to separate.

Comment: @cdkMoose In my country there is a distinction between landlord and owner. When someone subrents, they are legally landlord. I am completely responsible for the behavior of the subrentee and I am answerable to the owner/government (who is my landlord).

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't Do Business With Friends unless you're okay losing money or friendship (or both)

Plenty of people rent to friends, have friends work for them, and even loan money to friends without problems, but when the business relationship goes sour consider what that will mean to the friendship.

The rule for loans and friends is don't loan to a friend unless you're okay with giving the money away.  We can probably come up with a corollary about renting to friends that involves losing money.  The problems are when a "friend" feels like the relationship is less professional due to the friendship.

Comment: This is pretty much the only answer here - it's an old Truism, sadly.